# How to get Location Based posts using Firestore Geopoint for Social Media app (swift Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, location, geofire

My app already saves users image, name, email, and password. Its using firestore to handle the posts but I'm trying to get location based posts so when the user is in lets say a 20 mile area they can see posts just from that area. I believe I need to set the lat and long for each post based off current user location. I'm having trouble finding info on Geopoint and don't know how to implement it. I also read about GeoFirestore on GitHub and I don't know if I should incorporate that. Let me know what you think, anything helps! (swift Xcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the below link , its so helpful in getting Geocode data:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wxE8byc2FQ&t=1s